# Algorithm that will grab all nodes attached to a particular node

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am creating an algorithm that is based on directed graphs. I would like a function that will grab all the nodes that are attached to a particular node.

```
public List<Node> GetNodesInRange(Graph graph, int Range, Node selected)
{
    var result = new List<Node>();
    result.Add(selected);
    if (Range > 0)
    {
        foreach (Node neighbour in GetNeighbours(graph, selected))
        {
            result.AddRange(GetNodesInRange(graph, Range - 1, neighbour));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private List<Node> GetNeighbours(Graph graph, Node selected)
{
    foreach(Node node in graph.node)
    {
        if (node == selected)
        {
            GetNodesInRange(node, Range-1, /*don't know what 2 do here*/);
            //and confused all the way down
```

Comment: Voted to close because your question is way too vague.

Comment: Edited above so every1 can understand

Comment: How does this question differ from the question you asked a couple days ago?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657374/algorithm-to-use-to-return-a-specific-range-of-nodes-in-a-directed-graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which kind of implementation you are using for your graph:

- **edge list**: you search all edges that have the specified vertex as first or second parameter to the edge
- **adjacency list**: the list attached to a node is already the list of nodes incident to it
- **adjacency matrix**: you take the column (or row) of the vertex that you chose

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `GetNodesInRange` inside `GetNeighbours` and `GetNeighbours` inside `GetNodesInRange` and that is creating problem.

Look at the answer by [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664811/algorithm-that-will-grab-all-nodes-attached-to-a-particular-node/2664827#2664827).

And if you post how your `Graph`,`Node` and `Edge` looks like then we will be able to offer more help.